# Create a batch file that reads a file into java application?

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, filereader

Currently I have the batch file named `caveroute.bat` that runs a java application, I would like to be able to run it like this from the command line `caveroute.bat <file>` where `<file>` is the text file that is to be read into the application.

What would be the best approach to create a batch file that reads a file into java application? and have the java application read the file specified in the command line?

Comment: As the file will be read by your java program, all you need is to send to Java the argument received by your batch script.

Comment: @ernest_k do you have an example of this?